# How do I optimize chaining async requests in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have code that do requests chaining like **A->B->C** and I am using `URLSession` all requests are done in right order and with expected behavior. But i am wondering how I can optimize this chaining because it looks quite complex and not reusable. I am looking for the suggestion how I can do this chaining in more flexible way.

My code:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "first")!)){ data , res , err in
    let second = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "second")!)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: second){ data , res , err in
        let third = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "second")!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:third){ data , res , err in
         }.resume()
    }.resume()
}.resume()
```

Comment: OperationQueue with `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1`?

Comment: You can look at promisekit.

Comment: @MaxPevsner you mean to create Queues of the Requests and than execute them in sync order ?

Comment: @Paulw11 this is quite cool suggestion. I think this is I am looking for. Could you please post answer.

Comment: I'm sure that more elegant way to write this code wont fix architectural bug

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk not exactly. Create one `OperationQueue`, set its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 and add the requests to the queue. They will be performed one after another and not altogether.

Comment: I don't get all the fuss around promises. I find this pattern such an inelegant way of solving the problem of asyncs. You could start by naming your functions accordingly to their job and having them defined separately (not as anonymous functions, just like javascript folks proposing promises do).

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp  this is just elegant way to reduce nested code with usage of the chain of the responsibility pattern. But it is not a silver bullet. In some cases it is not suitable.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk I get it, but by using promises you don't explicitly say what the piece of code does, so the folks will have to read all your promises anyway to see that in the end, your fetchingA, then fetchingB, then fetchingC to computeD.

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp  yes but you are using optional chaining in swift and you learn how it is works really it is depending on the own preferences of code writing. My own opinion is easy to read code with less code lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Paulw11 suggested:

PromiseKit + PMKFoundation

```
import PromiseKit
import PMKFoundation

let session = URLSession.shared
firstly {
    session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "first")!))
} .then { data in
    session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "second")!))
} .then { data in
    session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "third")!))
} .then { data -> () in
    // The data here is the data fro the third URL
} .catch { error in
    // Any error in any step can be handled here
}
```

---

With 1 (and only 1) retry, you can use `recover`. `recover` is like `catch` except it's expected that the previous `then` can be retried. However, this is not a loop and executes only once.

```
func retry(url: URL, on error: Error) -> Promise<Data> {
    guard error == MyError.retryError else { throw error }

    // Retry the task if a retry-able error occurred.
    return session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url))
}

let url1 = URL(string: "first")!
let url2 = URL(string: "second")!
let url3 = URL(string: "third")!

let session = URLSession.shared
firstly {
    session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url1))
} .then { data in
    session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url2))
} .recover { error in
    retry(url: url2, on: error)
} .then { data in
    session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url3))
} .recover { error in
    retry(url: url3, on: error)
} .then { data -> () in
    // The data here is the data fro the third URL
} .catch { error in
    // Any error in any step can be handled here
}
```

NOTE: to make this work without specifying return types and needing a `return` statement, I need the `then` and `recover` to be 1 line exactly. So I create methods to do the processing.

Comment: nice code! is there any way to restart only second and third request in case of error in first one ?

Comment: @sage444 I can get close, see what you think.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can use dependencies using OperationQueues like below:

```
func operationQueueWithBlockandCancel(){

    let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main

    let operationBlock1 = BlockOperation()
    let operationBlock2 = BlockOperation()
    let operationBlock3 = BlockOperation()


    operationBlock1.addExecutionBlock {
       //Any task
    }

    operationBlock2.addExecutionBlock {
       //Any task
    }


    operationBlock3.addExecutionBlock {
        //Any task
    }

    //Add dependency as required
    operationBlock3.addDependency(operationBlock2)
    operationBlock2.addDependency(operationBlock1)

    opQueue.addOperations([operationBlock2,operationBlock1,operationBlock3,], waitUntilFinished: false)

}
```